# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Sending a Simple Message to a Service HTTP 404 error

Tags: http, wso2, http-status-code-404, esb

I am referring https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Quick+Start+Guide
I am trying to do Routing requests based on message content.
I am using WSO2 EI 6.5.0 as part of my preparation for WSO2EI developer exam.
Can anybody assist me why I am getting following error when follow exactly what is instructed in this page. Properly Installed WSO2 EI 6.5.0 as suggested. Running perfectly MSF4J and The ESB server of WSO2.

```
base) user@user-Lenovo-G400:~/wso2/WSO2 EI$ curl -v -X POST --data @request.json http://localhost:8280/healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve --header 'Content-Type:application/json'
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1:8280...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
    > POST /healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:8280
    > User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type:application/json
    > Content-Length: 285
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 285 out of 285 bytes
    * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
    < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    < Date: Sat, 02 Nov 2019 13:34:53 GMT
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    <
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Wirelogs:

```
(base) user@user-Lenovo-G400:~$ sudo wso2ei-6.5.0-integrator
/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/bin/integrator.sh: line 135: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,288] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.15.0-66-generic, amd64
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_201
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09,Oracle Corporation
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,330] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/wso2/tmp
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,331] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : wso2, en-US, Asia/Kolkata
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,526] [EI-Core]  INFO - DefaultCryptoProviderComponent 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,577] [EI-Core]  INFO - GoogleTokenGenDSComponent Activating GoogleTokengen DS component
[2019-11-03 18:30:00,755] [EI-Core]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2019-11-03 18:30:06,379] [EI-Core]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 107ms
[2019-11-03 18:30:06,563] [EI-Core]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2019-11-03 18:30:13,341] [EI-Core]  INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2019-11-03 18:30:13,837] [EI-Core]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2019-11-03 18:30:34,003] [EI-Core]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2019-11-03 18:30:35,279] [EI-Core]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
[2019-11-03 18:30:35,604] [EI-Core]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2019-11-03 18:30:35,604] [EI-Core]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,341] [EI-Core]  INFO - VFSTransportSender VFS Sender started
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,388] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,451] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,451] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,461] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,482] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,517] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,663] [EI-Core]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v35 - file:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v35.mar
[2019-11-03 18:30:36,667] [EI-Core]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v34 - file:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1-wso2v34.mar
[2019-11-03 18:30:37,246] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.store-4.6.150 - 
[2019-11-03 18:30:38,110] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor-4.6.150 - 
[2019-11-03 18:30:38,122] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.store-4.6.150 - 
[2019-11-03 18:30:38,729] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2019-11-03 18:30:38,755] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts-5.2.19 - 
[2019-11-03 18:30:38,880] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit-4.6.65 - 
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,145] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,224] [EI-Core]  INFO - TenantLoadingConfig Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,236] [EI-Core]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,280] [EI-Core]  INFO - RuleEngineConfigDS Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,719] [EI-Core]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB...
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,735] [EI-Core]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,743] [EI-Core]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/.
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,743] [EI-Core]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,743] [EI-Core]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name : localhost
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,753] [EI-Core]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,763] [EI-Core]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Sun Nov 03 18:30:39 IST 2019
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,773] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,776] [EI-Core]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,794] [EI-Core]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,872] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : fault was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,876] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : main was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,876] [EI-Core]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,877] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_HOST was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,877] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_IP was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,880] [EI-Core]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,886] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,886] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,894] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,895] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,911] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,913] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2019-11-03 18:30:39,999] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher undeployed successfully : MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,447] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventJunction WSO2EventConsumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,450] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher configuration successfully deployed and in active state : MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,450] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventStreamDeployer Stream definition is deployed successfully  : org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,469] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher undeployed successfully : MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,487] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventJunction WSO2EventConsumer added to the junction. Stream:org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,488] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher configuration successfully deployed and in active state : MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,488] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventStreamDeployer Stream definition is deployed successfully  : org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:40,858] [EI-Core]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/odata].File[/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/odata.war]
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,200] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: DOCTORS_DataService {super-tenant}
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,200] [EI-Core]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: DOCTORS_DataService.dbs - file:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/repository/deployment/server/dataservices/DOCTORS_DataService.dbs
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,200] [EI-Core]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service...
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,201] [EI-Core]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services...
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,202] [EI-Core]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying EventSources...
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,219] [EI-Core]  INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing...
[2019-11-03 18:30:43,261] [EI-Core]  INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent Global Message-Flow Statistic Reporting is Disabled
[2019-11-03 18:30:44,976] [EI-Core]  INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car...
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,633] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : QueryDoctorEP was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: SampleServicesCompositeApplication ] 
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,634] [EI-Core]  INFO - EndpointDeployer Endpoint named 'QueryDoctorEP' has been deployed from file : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1572786044978SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/QueryDoctorEP_1.0.0/QueryDoctorEP-1.0.0.xml
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,651] [EI-Core]  INFO - API Initializing API: HealthcareAPI
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,654] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : HealthcareAPI was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: SampleServicesCompositeApplication ] 
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,656] [EI-Core]  INFO - APIDeployer API named 'HealthcareAPI' has been deployed from file : /usr/lib/wso2/wso2ei/6.5.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1572786044978SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/HealthcareAPI_1.0.0/HealthcareAPI-1.0.0.xml
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,656] [EI-Core]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,664] [EI-Core]  INFO - VFSTransportListener VFS listener started
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,666] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,695] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,696] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,700] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,711] [EI-Core]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,783] [EI-Core]  INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2019-11-03 18:30:46,993] [EI-Core]  INFO - TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2019-11-03 18:30:47,028] [EI-Core]  INFO - NTaskTaskManager Initialized task manager. Tenant [-1234]
[2019-11-03 18:30:47,148] [EI-Core]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2019-11-03 18:30:47,150] [EI-Core]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Integrator-6.5.0
[2019-11-03 18:30:47,150] [EI-Core]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 56 sec
[2019-11-03 18:30:47,452] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://192.168.0.6:9443/carbon/
[2019-11-03 18:32:42,612] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "GET /healthcare/querydoctor/surgery HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:42,613] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Host: localhost:8280[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:42,613] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "User-Agent: curl/7.65.3[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:42,613] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:42,613] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,056] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator message = "Welcome to HealthcareService"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,070] [EI-Core]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,115] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "GET /healthcare/surgery HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,116] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "activityid: 989ebf9c-dff6-40ec-bf90-478f8f5b4ce1[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,116] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,116] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: localhost:9090[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,116] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,117] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,117] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,313] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,313] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,313] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 412[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,313] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,314] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2019-11-03 18:32:43,321] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> **"[{"name":"thomas collins","hospital":"grand oak community hospital","category":"surgery","availability":"9.00 a.m - 11.00 a.m","fee":7000.0},{"name":"anne clement","hospital":"clemency medical center","category":"surgery","availability":"8.00 a.m - 10.00 a.m","fee":12000.0},{"name":"seth mears","hospital":"pine valley community hospital","category":"surgery","availability":"3.00 p.m - 5.00 p.m","fee":8000.0}]"**
[2019-11-03 18:35:42,864] [EI-Core]  INFO - SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2019-11-03 18:35:42,865] [EI-Core]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:57096
```

Comment: Enable wirelogs and share the logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: After enabling wirelogs able to see the output in console, but curl still showing "Empty reply from server" and browser show nothing. Also How do I share the wirelogs?

Comment: You can either update the question with the logs or use an external tool like https://pastebin.com

Comment: As suggested edited the question with logs

Comment: The response has been received from the backend, but not to the client. Do you have anything inside the out sequence? Can you show the API synapse file?

Comment: I did n't see any file in src/main/synapse-config/proxy-services folder

Comment: it must be under api as it's an api.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/healthcare" name="HealthcareAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/querydoctor/{category}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Welcome to HealthcareService&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="QueryDoctorEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

Comment: /src/main/synapse-config/api/HealthcareAPI.xml. Content is pasted in above comment. I do appreciate your patience

Comment: The outSequence of the API seems to be empty. i.e. after sending the request out via the in sequence, the request won't be mediated back to the client. In order to mediate back to the client, could you modify the out sequence of API as follow and give it a try.  
<outSequence>
<send/>
</outSequence>